# chaining .add and .submit does not work as expected in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, compatibility

The following syntax works on Safari (osx), Chrome (win/osx), and Firefox (win/osx) - but does NOT work on non-metro IE 11 (windows 8.1).

```
var html = '<form id="theForm" name="theForm" action="/controller/action" method="POST">;
html += '<input type="hidden" name="bob" value="-1" />';
html += '</form>';

//  I expect this to work in IE as it does in all other browsers.
$(document).add(html).submit();
```

Is this a bug or have I done something incorrect?

Comment: Why are you appending HTML to `document`? I think you want to append it to the `body` element.

Comment: I tried with body as well:  `$('BODY').append(html).sumbit();` - still no joy.

Comment: I did make it work cross browser, but I had to assign an ID to the form, then ask for the form by id before calling submit.  I was wondering why the chaining method didn't work in IE but did in all other browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are having some chaining issues. I think you want to append your `html` string to the `body` element (not `document`), and submit `form` element. You are on the right track with `$('BODY').append(html).sumbit();`, but the `submit` is being called on the `body` element, rather than the `form` element.

Instead, create a jQuery object collection from the `html` string, append it to the `body`, then `submit` it.

```
$(html).appendTo('body').submit();
```

### Example:

```
var html = '<form id="theForm" name="theForm" action="/controller/action" method="POST">';
html += '<input type="hidden" name="bob" value="-1" />';
html += '</form>';
$(html).appendTo('body').submit();
```